# High CPU Usage when logged into Wordpress admin console

Tags: wordpress, cpu-usage

When viewing the site there are no issues, but when I log into my admin area, and edit pages etc  I  sees large spikes in cpu usage and the WP console is super slow when saving and reloading.  The Error logs give different range of errors each day. I've disabled heartbeat. Deleted database bloat. Deactivated  plugins. I have WP Rocket and use the Avada theme

Please see screenshots that of issues here
https://www.heritagecentralotago.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/ERROR-LOG.pdf
Many thanks for your help!